# Bending arrow in XY-Pic diagram

Tags: diagrams, arrows, xy-pic

In the diagram with bending arrow given by the LaTeX file below,
the arrow has a misdirected head.

How can I correct it?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\[    \xymatrix@1@R=7pt@C=10pt{
& 0 \ar@{-}[rd] &&&&  1\ar@{-}[ld] \\
&& a\ar@{-}[r] & \cdots  \ar@{-}[r] & b \\
&2\ar@{-}[ru] &&&& 
3\ar@{-}[lu] \ar@{-->} `d[dl] `[lllll] `[uu] \\ 
&&&&
 }   \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I heartily wish that bending arrows were more clearly explained in the manual of Xy-pic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution is in the following code. Essentially I just added one more relative positioning parameter to get the arrowhead to turn the correct direction. Also, I changed the variant of the arrow head `\ar@{--2>}` to make the arrow more distinct.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
    \[    \xymatrix@1@R=7pt@C=10pt{
        & 0 \ar@{-}[rd] &&&&  1\ar@{-}[ld] \\
        && a\ar@{-}[r] & \cdots  \ar@{-}[r] & b \\
        &2\ar@{-}[ru] &&&& 
        3\ar@{-}[lu] \ar@{--2>} `d[dl] `[lllll] `[uu] [uullll] \\  
        &&&&
    }   \]
\end{document}
```

[image: Example Image]

Comment: How can one put a picture in one's question or answer?

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi: You're welcome! To add a picture to the answer box you can press the little box that looks like a landscape (at the top of the editor) and then either upload an image from your computer, or through a url, or you can do Ctrl-G on Windows.

Comment: @cptnjtk, not only on Windows. I use Linux and `ctrl+g` works.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get the whole arrow dashed, you will have to switch to [tikz-cd](/questions/tagged/tikz-cd):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[every arrow/.append style={dash}]
0 \arrow{dr} & &[.8cm] & 1 \\
& a \arrow{r}[description]{\ldots} & b \arrow{ur}\arrow{dr} & \\
2 \arrow{ur} & & & 3 \arrow[->, dashed, rounded corners, to path={ -- ([yshift=-2ex]\tikztostart.south) -| ([xshift=-2ex]\tikztotarget.west) -- (\tikztotarget)}]{uulll}
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! I will certainly switch to {tikz-cd}! Unfortunately, I cannot accept two answers....

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi Glad to hear that. You do not have to accept both. The other one answers your question. I am just giving another approach. It is absolutely worth to have a look into the `tikz-cd` manual.