# Bending arrows in tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, arrows, tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

Following the advice of LaRiFaRi in an answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248813/bending-arrow-in-xy-pic-diagram),
I switched from `XY-Pic` to `tikz-cd`. 
The file below contains my diagram in `XY-Pic` and in `tikz-cd`. 
Please help me to make my diagram in `tikz-cd` beautiful!

I would like:

1. To improve the problematic arrow from $\ell-1$ to 1;
2. To make the arrow tips sharper, as in `XY-Pic`;
3. To make the solid lines touch (or at least almost touch) the small circles.

Note that my diagram is an (affine) Dynkin diagram, so it should look as a Dynkin diagram, see [these pictures](https://www.google.ca/search?q=affine+dynkin+diagram&espv=2&biw=1032&bih=729&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CDwQsARqFQoTCJemofiehMYCFY1ekgod_6oAsA).

EDIT: I took the corrected arrow from LaRiFaRi's answer and found suitable arrow tips in the library following his advice. Now the diagram is nicer than that of `XY-Pic`. Still I need solid lines coming closer to the small circles. Find below the corrected diagram.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\def\ccc{{  \lower0.3ex\hbox{{\text{\Large$\circ$}}}}}
\newcommand{\bc}[1]{{\overset{#1}{\ccc}}}
\newcommand{\bcu}[1]{{\underset{#1}{\ccc}}}

\begin{document}
\[   \xymatrix@1@R=-5pt@C=10pt{
& \bc{0} \ar@{-}[rd]\ar@/^0.75pc/@{-->}[rrrr] &&  &&\bc{\ell-1}\ar@{-}[ld]
    \ar@{-->} `l[lld]  `[lldd]  [lllldd] \\
&&\bc{2}\ar@{-}[r] & \cdots  \ar@{-}[r] & \bc{\ell-2} \\
&\bc{1}\ar@{-}[ru] \ar@/_0.7pc/@{-->}[rrrr] & &  & &\bc{\ell}\ar@{-}[lu]
    \ar@{--2>} `d[l] `l[lllll] `[uu]  [lllluu] \\
}   \]
\bigskip

\[  \begin{tikzcd}[every arrow/.append style={dash},row sep=-5pt, column sep=10pt]
\bc{0} \arrow{dr} \arrow[thin,-{Stealth[open]}, dashed,bend left=20]{rrr} 
 & &[.8cm] & \bc{\ell-1}
 \arrow[thin,-{Stealth[open]}, dashed, rounded corners, 
        to path={ -- ([xshift=-1.795cm]\tikztostart.west) |- 
        (\tikztotarget)}]{llldd}
\\
& \bc{2} \arrow{r}[description]{\ldots} & \bc{\ell-2} \arrow{ur}\arrow{dr} &
\\
\bc{1}\arrow[thin,-{Stealth[open]}, dashed,bend right=20]{rrr}\arrow{ur} &
       & & \bc{\ell}
       \arrow[thin,-{Stealth[open]}, dashed, rounded corners, 
            to path={ -- ([yshift=-2ex]\tikztostart.south) -|
            ([xshift=-1.5ex]\tikztotarget.west) -- (\tikztotarget)}]{uulll}
\end{tikzcd}  \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the `dynkin-diagrams` package. This example is included in the documentation. Note that by default, the affine root of this D series diagram is marked with a white circle, while the other roots have solid circles; you can easily change this if you don't like it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}
\tikzset{big arrow/.style={
    -Stealth,line cap=round,line width=1mm,
    shorten <=1mm,shorten >=1mm}}
\newcommand\catholic[2]{\draw[big arrow,green!25!white] 
(root #1) to (root #2);}
\newcommand\protestant[2]{
\begin{scope}[transparency group, opacity=.25]
\draw[big arrow,orange] (root #1) to (root #2);
\end{scope}}
\begin{document}
\begin{dynkinDiagram}[edge length=1.2cm,
indefinite edge/.style={thick,loosely dotted},
labels*={0,1,2,3,\ell-3,\ell-2,\ell-1,\ell}]{D}[1]{}
\catholic{0}{6}\catholic{1}{7}
\protestant{7}{0}\protestant{6}{1}
\end{dynkinDiagram}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this?

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=-5pt, column sep=10pt,cells={nodes={draw, circle,font=\tiny, inner sep=2pt, minimum size=24pt}}]
     1 \arrow[dash]{dr} \arrow[dashed,bend left=25]{rrr} & &[.8cm] & 
     \ell-1 \arrow[dashed, rounded corners, to path={ -- ([xshift=-1.795cm]\tikztostart.west) |- (\tikztotarget)}]{llldd}
    \\
    & 2 \arrow[dash]{r}[description]{\ldots} & \ell-2 \arrow[dash]{ur}\arrow[dash]{dr} & 
    \\
    1 \arrow[dash]{ur} & & & 
    \ell \arrow[dashed,bend left=25]{lll} \arrow[dashed, rounded corners, to path={ -- ([yshift=-2ex]\tikztostart.south) -| ([xshift=-1.5ex]\tikztotarget.west) -- (\tikztotarget)}]{uulll}
\end{tikzcd}  
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have not changed the arrow tips as the ones from `xy` are just ugly. If you want to change to some other style, just look into the manual. `xy` arrow heads are not included asaif.

Comment: Dear @LaRiFaRi, this is very beautiful, but not what I need. I need a labeled graph: small circles and small numbers/symbols near the small circles. The solid lines should come very close to the circles (maybe even touch them). I have edited my file in the question, taking in account your answer. Still I don't know how to make the solid lines come closer to the small circles.